# Increase Title Margin in Mobile view only

Tags: html, css, blogs

Everything looks great on desktop. But in the mobile view I'm seeing blog titles overlapping the blog teasers on my blog page. I am trying to add margins to the bottom of the blog post titles for the mobile view only:
[image]

I've tried adding this css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) { .entry-container .entry-title { margin-bottom:15px; }}
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is a copy of the div with its classes:

```html
<div class="entry-container"><header class="entry-header"><h2 class="entry-title"><a class="entry-title-link" rel="bookmark" href="https://avt.850.myftpupload.com/why-we-became-financial-advisors/">Why We Became Financial Advisors</a></h2>
</header><div class="entry-content"><p>Would you hand over your house keys to a stranger? That’s often what it feels like to work with a financial advisor. Not only do …</p><p class="more-link-wrap"><a href="https://avt.850.myftpupload.com/why-we-became-financial-advisors/" class="more-link button text">Continue Reading <span class="screen-reader-text">about Why We Became Financial Advisors</span></a></p></div><footer class="entry-footer"><div class="alignleft"><img alt="" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/895fdbf242e920205673491b0b5b2b80?s=46&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g" srcset="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/895fdbf242e920205673491b0b5b2b80?s=92&amp;d=mm&amp;r=g 2x" class="avatar avatar-46 photo" height="46" width="46" loading="lazy"></div><p class="entry-meta"><span class="entry-author">Written by:<br><a href="https://avt.850.myftpupload.com/author/kourtneykearney/" class="entry-author-link" rel="author"><span class="entry-author-name">Kourtney Kearney</span></a></span><span class="entry-date"><time class="entry-time">Published on:<br><span class="entry-time-date">September 2, 2021</span></time></span> <span class="entry-comments-link">Thoughts:<br><a href="https://avt.850.myftpupload.com/why-we-became-financial-advisors/#respond">No comments yet</a></span></p></footer></div>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce this issue with a limited details, have you deployed your code on any server ? If yes then please share the link. Thank you

Comment: @HassanSiddiqui -- testing site is https://avt.850.myftpupload.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just review the provided Test link, the issue is not related to **Title** or **Responsive**.

Actually `margin-top: -60px!important;` CSS added on **.entry-content** and `margin-bottom: 65px;` CSS on **.entry-header**.

**Step 1:**

Remove `margin-top: -60px!important;` CSS from **.entry-content**.

**Step 2:**

Change `margin-bottom: 65px;` CSS to `margin-bottom: 0;` on **.entry-header**.

Will resolve your issue on Both Desktop and Responsive versions. Thank You

Comment: thanks! That worked!  Makes sense to adjust the object that occurs first :)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you can check:

- `min-width: 700px` to `max-width: 1000px` is not mobile view. It is usually tablet size. So if you're checking on smaller screen sizes, your CSS might not get applied.
- As you can see in the snippet you pasted, normal divs will be positioned correctly one after the other without an overlap even when there is no margin set. So check if you've have a height set on `.entry-container`, `.entry-header`, `.entry-title` `h2.entry-title`. This is probably causing the header to overflow and thus overlap on the content below.